# split a vector into chunk until an event occurs

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

I Have a vector `x <- c("H","H","T","H","T","T","H","H","H","H","T")` from a coin flip. I Want to construct a Data frame with two variables (pattern, length) from the above vector.

Pattern field will be like {H H T, H T, T, H H H H T} and the corresponding length would be {2,1,0,4}

My intension is to get count of continuous head, until a tail appears in the coin flip.

Answer (score 4):

Given the vector

```
x <- c("H","H","T","H","T","T","H","H","H","H","T")

diff(c(0, as.integer(gregexpr("T", paste0(x, collapse = ""))[[1]]) ) ) - 1
# [1] 2 1 0 4
```

---

**Explanation**

Collapse the vector into a string

```
paste0(x, collapse = "")
## "HHTHTTHHHHT"
```

Find the location of all the `T`s

```
as.integer(gregexpr("T", paste0(x, collapse = ""))[[1]])
## [1]  3  5  6 11
```

The number of `H` between the `T`s will be the difference between each value, minus 1

Append a leading `0` and find the difference between each value.

```
diff(c(0, as.integer(gregexpr("T", paste0(x, collapse = ""))[[1]]) ) ) - 1
[1] 2 1 0 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rle` to count all H between T then add the zero H series:

```
x  <- c("H","H","T","H","T","T","H","H","H","H","T")
y <- rle(x=='T')
table(c(rep(0,sum(y$lengths[y$values & y$lengths>1]-1)),y$lengths[!y$values]))


0 1 2 4 
1 1 1 1
```

Comment: I don't think this quite answers the question; the OP is after the number of continuous `H`, including where there are 0 Hs between a `T`